# How to change the style of a single component within an other component with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm working on an react app with styled-components and I have a component 'Navigation'. In this component are more components like , , etc.
Header for example is declared like this:

`` const Header = styled.div`
  height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in; ``

Thing is that I have this Navigation component in different files and for all of them the styling is good but now I want to change the background color of the Header component in just one of those files, which is within(?) the Navigation component. How can I do that?
I know that it's possible to change the styling from the Navigation component with something like **const NewNav = styled(Navigation)``** but what about the Header?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should define your `Header` as a separate component and import the component to your `Navigation` component aren't it

Comment: Is this really the normal thing people do? I find it a bit much to import 8 "child"-components just to have my navigation component on a profile e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [pass props](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) through your navigation component to your header.

```
<NavigationExample secondary />
```

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

function NavigationExample(props) {
  const { secondary } = props;

  return (
    <Navigation>
      <Header secondary={secondary}>
        ...
      </Header>
      <Profile>
        username
      <Profile>
    </Navigation>
  );
}

const Navigation = styled.nav;

const Header = styled.header`
  /* Base styles */
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;

  ${props => props.secondary && css`
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
  `;
`;

const Profile = styled.div``;

export default NavigationExample;
```

Alternatively, you can [inline props in your css](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props).

```
<NavigationExample backgroundColor="#222" />
```

```
const Header = styled.header`
  /* Base styles */
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: ${props => props.backgroundColor || '#222'};
  color: ${props => props.backgroundColor ? '#000' : '#fff'}; /* Adjusting text so it's legible like the previous example */
`;
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that I could pass props also the other way around. Worked great for me.